# Statically iterate over all members of a C++ struct

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Is there a way to statically iterate over all members of a C++ struct?

Say if we have many predefined structs which look like:

```
struct Foo {
    int field1;
    double field2;
    char field3;
    ...
    int field9;
};
struct Bar {
    double field14;
    char field15;
    int field16;
    bool field17;
    ...
    double field23;
};
```

And we want to have a template function

```
template<typename T>
void Iterate(T object);
```

so that `Iterate` can run a template function `Add` over all the members of type `T`. For example, `Iterate<Foo>` and `Iterate<Bar>` would become

```
void Iterate<Foo>(Foo object) {
    Add<int>(object.field1);
    Add<double>(object.field2);
    Add<char>(object.field3);
    ...
    Add<int>(object.field9);
}
void Iterate<Bar>(Bar object) {
    Add<double>(object.field14);
    Add<char>(object.field15);
    Add<int>(object.field16);
    Add<bool>(object.field17);
    ...
    Add<double>(object.field23);
}
```

This can be done by writing another program that parses the `struct` definition and generate a `cpp` file, but that would be too cumbersome and requires additional compiling and execution.

Edit: The struct may have many fields, and they are predefined, so it can't be changed into other types. Also this is at compile-time, so it has less to do with "reflection", which is performed at run-time, and more to do with "template programming" or "metaprogramming". We have `<type_traits>` for type inspection at compile-time, but that does not seem to be enough.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). I tried something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251815/creating-an-array-initializer-from-a-tuple-or-variadic-template-parameters)  and have the solution in production.

Comment: To me this is a fundamental design aspect. Use of heterogeneous container perhaps.

Comment: c++ doesn't have reflection.

Comment: Have you looked at the Boost serialization library?

Answer (score 6):

There is no clear standard way to do such thing, but you can look at non-standard way. For example you can use `boost::fusion`.

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
   Foo,
   (int, field1)
   (double, field2)
   (char, field3)
);
```

[adapt struct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html)
After that, you can use objects of type `Foo` as fusion-sequence, which can be iterated by member.
[small live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13f867af03637b7f)

Comment: Looks interesting. But it still requires user to somewhat redefine the struct.

Comment: @WiSaGaN yes, but you can either use BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT, that will just define struct in namespace which you want.

Comment: (I upvoted this answer, this is just a comment in addition to it) Until reflection gets added to the standard, you need to manually provide the extra metadata; who knows, maybe in the future boost_adapt_struct may use reflection; that's an argument to using a library rather than rolling your own...

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way to do this with a normal struct without retaining compile time information for the mapping of indices to types - at which point you create another std::tuple class.  Let's give this a try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template <size_t Cur, size_t Last, class TupleType, template <typename> class Func>
struct Iterate_Helper
{
    void operator()(TupleType& tuple)
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<Cur, TupleType>::type elem_type;
        Func<elem_type>()(std::get<Cur>(tuple));
        Iterate_Helper<Cur+1, Last, TupleType, Func>()(tuple);
    }
};

template <size_t Cur, class TupleType, template <typename> class Func>
struct Iterate_Helper<Cur, Cur, TupleType, Func>
{
    void operator()(TupleType& tuple)
    {
        typedef typename std::tuple_element<Cur, TupleType>::type elem_type;
        Func<elem_type>()(std::get<Cur>(tuple));
    }
};

template <template <typename> class Func, class TupleType>
void iterate(TupleType& tuple)
{
    Iterate_Helper<0, std::tuple_size<TupleType>::value-1, TupleType, Func>()(tuple);
}

template <typename T>
struct Add1
{
    void operator()(T& t)
    {
        t += 1;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Print
{
    void operator()(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << (int)t << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef std::tuple<int, double, char, /* ... */ int> Foo;
    Foo test(1, 2.0, 3, 4);
    iterate<Add1>(test);
    iterate<Print>(test);        
    return 0;
}
```

This is on top of my head but I hope it can give you some insight.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is well supported with Boost.Fusion and the extension mechanism.

You can find a for_each_member implementation here : https://github.com/cpp-pre/json/blob/master/pre/fusion/for_each_member.hpp

I use it to generate JSON and read structs from json as explained in my other reply here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580824/271781

Comment: Repository moved here : https://github.com/cpp-pre/json/blob/master/pre/fusion/for_each_member.hpp