# Going from type and offset to member pointer: offsetof inverse?

Tags: c++

The `offsetof(type, member)` returns the offset value in bytes from the beginning of the layout of `type` to its `member`.

I am pretty sure the language does not provide a way to do the reciprocal: a `memberof(type, offset)` to go from a type and offset to a pointer to member. Is there a way to achieve that? Without abusing the language? In a cross-platform way? In a constexpr way?

```
struct my_type_t type {
  var_type_t m_var;
};
```

I can do:

```
size_t offset_in_bytes = offsetof(my_type_t, m_var);
```

I am looking for:

```
var_type_t my_type_t::* ptr_to_var_member = memberof(my_type_t, offset_in_bytes);
```

Comment: Why do you need a pointer-to-member? If you have an offset, start, and known type, you can obtain a regular pointer to the member.

Comment: Maybe using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687455/statically-iterate-over-all-members-of-a-c-struct) and try to match the offset to identify the member.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: if I have a type, it does not mean I have a pointer to an instance that would allow me to obtain a regular pointer - I might want to just keep the pointer to member around until I have a pointer to the known type instance.

Comment: Why not just keep the offset around then?